# Regex - Query, Isolating

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string.

> Andrew - BOB - Jay vs John

Now all Four names can change at any time, my only true concern however is with isolating Jay vs John independent of the names before the constant in this, is that the format always follows

```
world1 - world2 - X vs Y
```

How do I check for X vs Y disregarding the first 2?

I've tried.

```
'%- (.*?) Vs (.*)$%';
```

TO no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also - following a suggestion how do I deal with the test case in which I wish to disregard everything to the far left other than the name of the two participants -- examples include..

```
www.GrindTimeNow.NET: Magz vs K-mo (Tryouts)

SMACK/ URL PRESENTS JC VS GA

POISONPEN.TV PRESENTS PH VS DIRT BAG DAN

KOTD - Rap Battle - Arsonal vs Illmaculate

DON'T FLOP - ‬Rap Battle - Arkaic Vs Dekay
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you just need to capture two names separated by 'vs' and some space. This should work:

```
%(\w+)\s+vs\s+(\w+)%i
```

[See a demo at regexr](http://regexr.com?31f1q)

Comment: I understand that and appreciate it works in theory but surely in practical use -

Comment: What if either of the items on each side of 'vs' are more than one word. 

Eg. 

John Davies vs Bob Smith? or even worse. 

JABBA JABBA JABBA VS FOO FOO FOO NINJA ?

Comment: You need to **clearly define** and state your requirements then. Your one example is with one first name for each person, so you got a regex that works perfectly for that one case. Edit your question with more test cases, and I can update my answer. Otherwise, nobody can read your mind.